# Broken Emacs26 Installation

Tags: apt, emacs

So I tried installing Emacs via this PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs26
```

I then get this error.

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-bin-common : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 emacs-el : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 emacs-gtk : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I proceed to run this command.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I get this response

```
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el', which is also in package emacs26-common 26.2~1.gitfd1b34b-kk1+19.04
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Would anyone have any idea of what I could try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after upgrading my dependencies via

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It started working again. I guess the version I had was broken and now it is not[